# How to transfer a variable from script to another in Godot

Tags: godot

I have 3 sprites A, B and C, each one has area2d attached to it and collision shape

the script for A

```
extends Area2D
var done = 0

func _input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if event.type == InputEvent.MOUSE_BUTTON \
    and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT \
    and event.pressed:
        get_parent().hide()
        done = 1
```

And all like that

Now the main node has a script attached to it

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    if get_node("lA").get("done")==1 && get_node("B").get("done")==1 && get_node("C").get("done")==1:
            get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/scene2.tscn")
```

But it doesn't work, why?

The error when doing `if get_node("lA").done == 1` is

`Invalid get index 'done' (on base: 'Sprite').`

What I'm trying to do is collect some items, when done, move to a new scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this QA post](https://godotengine.org/qa/1776/using-scripting-access-variable-from-another-nodes-gdscript) you should be able to access your variable doing `get_node("node").variable`

If that doesn't work try using a getter method for your variable:

```
var done = 0 setget ,done_get

func done_get()
    return done
```

Comment: I tried the first method, edited my question to indicate that. I should place that function in each of the scripts? and how to call it from the main node script?

Comment: You put that function in the script that has the variable `done`. And you access it like any other function `get_node("node").done_get()` or by the above method.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you get an invalid index error is that not your Sprite node holds the done variable but the Area2D node. That means you have to use:

```
if get_node("1A/Area2D").done == 1 and get_node("B/Area2D").done ...:
    get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/scenes2.tscn")
```

If you renamed the Area2D node you must change the names accordingly.

Hope that helps.